# How can I fix mismatch error in scala where the found : Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Seq required: scala.collection.Seq?

Tags: java, scala

This is the error:

```
<console>:123: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[scalismo.geometry.Landmark[scalismo.geometry._3D]]]
 required: scala.collection.Seq[scalismo.geometry.Landmark[scalismo.geometry._3D]]
            val rigidTrans = LandmarkRegistration.rigid3DLandmarkRegistration(landmarks, reflandmarks.toSeq)
```

Following the code snippet:

```
val alignedSet = toAlign.map { mesh =>    
  val landmarks = pointIds.map{id => Landmark("L_"+id, mesh.point(PointId(id)))}
  val rigidTrans = LandmarkRegistration.rigid3DLandmarkRegistration(landmarks, reflandmarks.toSeq)
  mesh.transform(rigidTrans)
}
```

Comment: You appear to be passing a `Seq[Seq[X]]` where a `Seq[X]` is required. Try `pointIds.flatMap(...` instead and see what happens.

Comment: It seems like the problem might have stem from `reflandmarks` instead of `pointIds`. At some point of the code before the provided snippet a `map` should have been `flatMap`. I can only suggest that you try flattening it with `reflandmarks.flatten` base of the limited code provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, in short the error is `found Seq[Seq[X]]; required Seq[X]`. Although your post does not show the *error location* (caret `^` in the console), I suspect this is for `reflandmarks.toSeq`. So `reflandmarks.toSeq` gives the `Seq[Seq[X]]`. To flatten a nested sequence, you can use `flatten`, so probably using `reflandmarks.toSeq.flatten` will work.

Note that because of subtyping, passing an argument `collection.immutable.Seq` where a `collection.Seq` is required, is always possible, so this has nothing to do with the actual problem.